# Making game characters (based on real people in history) for an educational game; is it Halal?

Tags: halal-haram, game, art, cartoon

I am a game artist. I make different types of **characters** for a game. Our team is willing to make a battleground game where gamers can learn about history by playing this game. If I make different types of characters like *Hitler* or *Abraham Lincoln*, is it **Halal**? What does Islam say about my perspective? Please answer in **details**, I am really worried about it.

Answer (score -1):

Haram, there are [narrations](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/39806/ruling-on-drawing-animate-beings) stating that the Prophet forbade drawing human beings with their faces, and they'll be punished the most severely on the day of judgement. It's up to you now, because school will not lead you in Jannah

Answer (score -1):

Yes it  is halal because your doing something productive with your time it's not alegal or haram.you have nothing to worry about God likes us to be humble and extremely well behaved so keep up the good work asalamualaikum.

Answer (score -1):

Haram, Ibn Mas`ud (May Allah be pleased with him) said: I heard the Messenger of Allah (PBUH) saying, "Those who will receive the most severe punishment from Allah on the Day of Resurrection will be painters (of living objects).''
[Al-Bukhari and Muslim].